# Strange Rewriting (Apache mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, windows, apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm very much confused about the result of my rewrite-rules. I use WAMP to host on my local machine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /niklasrosenstein/

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !res/(.+)$
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !index.php$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$            index.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

Going to

> http://localhost/niklasrosenstein/res

expands to

> http://localhost/niklasrosenstein/res/?uri=res

in the *browsers'* address-bar. I have tested it under Firefox 14, Opera 11.62 and Internet Explorer 8.

Adding a slash at the end of the URL, which would be

> http://localhost/niklasrosenstein/res/

is ok.

Does anyone know why the URL is adjusted in the browsers' address-bar? I want to use *mod_rewrite* in order to get rid of the fuzzy URL formatting, but that issue actually breaks it down..

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why the URL is adjusted in the browsers' address-bar?

This looks like a mod_dir/mod_rewrite conflict. By default, mod_dir is loaded, and the directory module's defaults are to have:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
DirectorySlash On
```

The second default makes it so anytime a request appears to access a directory, and is missing a trailing slash, 301 redirect to the same URI with the slash. This happens somewhere in the URI-file mapping pipeline and is interferring with the internal rewrite that mod_rewrite applies via your rules

Since you are routing everything through `index.php`, it may not be [detrimental to turn off DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash), so in the htaccess file in your `/niklasrosenstein/` directory, try turning it off:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Otherwise, you can try handling that using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond !.+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [L]
```